# how do I limit scopes in my Google Drive app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

When I click to edit my app in Google, it shows only one scope which is to edit only the files created by the app in Google Drive. The app has been verified by Google.

When I run the app on my phone, it brings up the warning screen that says, "Chess Openings Wizard wants access to your Google Account" and then it shows two options with checkboxes. The two options:

"See, edit, delete and create all of your Google Drive files."

"See, edit, create and delete only the
specific Google Drive files you use with this app."

Given that the app settings has only the second scope, why is the first checkbox there? How do I change things so that only the second scope is shown?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the default values in the scopes property of the TMS FNC Cloud Pack component. Those default values exceeded the scope that was authorized by Google.

Clearing the scopes property and then adding back only the authorized scoped fixed the issue.